# Cycle through text

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an HTML tag that will cycle through an array of words, displaying one word at a time, but changing every n seconds.

For example, let's say I have an array of `["one", "two", "three"]` and a span tag. The span tag's text would be `one` for n seconds, then change to `two`, then change to `three`, then change to `one`, etc...

Here's my attempt so far:

My `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeName();
  } 

  words: string[] = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  ];

  Wording: string = this.words[0];

  changeName():void {
    this.words.unshift(this.words[this.words.length - 1]);
    this.words.pop();
    this.Wording = this.words[0]
    var x = 5;  

    setTimeout(this.changeName, x*1000);
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`:

```
<span id="text-change">{{ Wording }}</span>
```

The above implementation does not change the text in the span tag, and has an error that `words` variable is undefined:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined
    at push../src/app/header/header.component.ts.HeaderComponent.changeName (header.component.ts:24)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3645)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
    at timer (zone.js:2054)
```

So my questions are:
1) First and foremost; is there a better way to do this?
2) Why is the `words` variable "disappearing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Observables would be an easier option for you. The following would work and is much cleaner in the end.

```
private words: string[] = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

rotateWords() {
  const source = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(this.words.length);
  const sub = source.finally(this.rotateWords).subscribe(i => console.log(this.words[i]));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can use setInterval and logic like this

```
changeName():void { 

  if(count === this.words.length){
    count = 0
  }
  this.Wording = this.words[count++] 
}

var x = 5; 
var count = 0;
setInterval(this.changeName, x*1000);
```

Demo

```js
function changeName() { 
    
      if(count === words.length){
        count = 0
      }
      console.log(words[count++]) 
 }
  var words = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three"
  ];
    var x = 5; 
    var count = 0;
    setInterval(changeName, x*1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

2) The words array is disappearing because you are using the `pop` method, which removes elements from the array. [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

1) I believe that a better way of achieving this is by using and maintaining an index yourself, as such:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.changeName(0);
    } 

    words: string[] = [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    ];

    var x = 5;

    Wording: string = this.words[0];

    changeName(index):void {
        this.Wording = this.words[index++];

        if (index == this.words.length) {
            index = 0;
        }

        return setTimeout(function () {
            this.changeName(index)
        }, x*1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ts file:

```
    words:any[]=["one", "two", "three"];

    word:string="";
    currentIdx:number =0;
    x=5;

    ngOnInit(){
      setInterval(()=>{
        this.rotateWords()
      },this.x*1000)
      }

  rotateWords(){

    if(this.currentIdx>=this.words.length){
      this.currentIdx=0;
    }

          this.word=this.words[this.currentIdx];
          this.currentIdx++
  }
```

In your html:

```
<p>{{word}}</p>
```